# Consulta sobre vistas a mostrar PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Hola gente tengo una consulta que no puedo resolver y necesito hacerlo ya que voy a usarlo en varias vistas.
Lo que necesito hacer es que cuando vaya a la seccion Registro / Login la pagina me quite algunas vistas, solo necesito dejar la cabecera , el menu y abajo de todo el footer (Osea quitar la imagen grande, las 3 imagenes de abajo y los productos (ver foto)). En mi index.php solo hago un require_once del header y a partir de aqui en los archivos html empiezo a incluir desde cada archuivo el menu , el slider , el banner y los productos. Osea, desde header.php hago un require_once de menu.php, en menu hago un require_once del slider y asi sucesivamente Al hacer click en registrar (usuarios/registro) necesito que el formulario aparezca justo debajo del menu, sin todo el otro contenido. Dejo una imagen para entenderlo mejor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
require_once 'autoload.php';
require_once 'delete_bom.php';
require_once 'config/db.php';
require_once 'config/parameters.php';
require_once 'helpers/utils.php';
require_once 'views/layout/header.php';
?>
```

Comment: Podrias utilizar ajax para hacer lo que estas necesitando para tu pagina. Te recomiendo leer lo siguiente para que tengas una idea: https://www.imaginanet.com/blog/usando-ajax-un-simple-ejemplo-con-php-y-jquery.html

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero no se me ocurre como podría ayudarme ajax. Mi problema no es que recarga la pagina sino que en todos los links a los que ingreso siempre me aparece la imagen grande y las 3 imagenes de abajo y no se como quitarlas.

Comment: tendrias que agregar el codigo de tu archivo php donde estan las imagenes que carga para que logre entenderlo mejor

Comment: Hola! tiene toda la pinta que donde puedes editar eso es en views/layout/header.php . Estaria bien que pusieses en la pregunta el codigo de ese php.

Comment: Hola, pude resolverlo de la siguiente forma, realmente no se si esta bien pero fue la unica forma que se me ocurrio:

 public static function isIndex()
    {
        $enlace_actual = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        if ($enlace_actual === base_url) {
            require_once 'views/layout/slider.php';
        }
    }